# Cloud flare visitor IP

Tags: php, jquery, cloudflare

I am trying to get real IP for visitors When I echo in php , its getting me my real IP

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS'];
```

But when I try to do this in jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
function(data){
   alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);
});
</script>
```

CloudFlare IP is returned, I enabled the `mod_cloudflare` in my apache

Comment: I've never used `mod_cloudflare`, but I know they but the original visitor's IP in `$_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']`.

Comment: Why would `http://jsonip.appspot.com` have anything to do with CloudFlare being installed on *your* server?

Comment: @RocketHazmat http://jsonip.appspot.com have nothing with cloudflare but it is a way to get my IP with JQuery.

Comment: @RocketHazmat how to link $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] with JQuery ip ?

Comment: jQuery runs on the client, not the server.  I don't understand how that API would be showing your server's (or CloudFlare's) IP.  Unless... How are you accessing the page with the jQuery on it?  Is it via `http://localhost`?  Or via `http://yourdomain.com`?

Comment: check this 
http://www.altibbi.com/tips/test.
i echo the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS']; and  alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);

Comment: I see a 404 image with a bunch of other garbage on the page.

Comment: @RocketHazmat try now pelase

Comment: It's (possibly) because of the ["Rocket Loader"](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-optimizer).  Try turning that off.

Comment: @RocketHazmat If I am trying to do it without turning off Rocket Loader. for frontend performance

Comment: Well, thing is... that's the issue here.  Rocket Loader is running your JavaScript, so it thinks your IP is CloudFlare.  You need to either a) turn off Rocket Loader for the script tag that gets your IP (not sure if you can do that), or b) make an AJAX call to your own server to get the IP (just have it echo `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS']`).

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes , thats the problem

Comment: Or, more specifically, the issue is that your JSONP call is being ran as `http://www.altibbi.com/cdn-cgi/pe/bag2?r[]=http%3A%2F%2Fjsonip.appspot.com%2F%3Fcallback%3DjQuery172032044627936556935_1396882311139%26_%3D1396882313159`.  It's being proxied through your server.  That's why the IP is your server's (CloudFlare's).  The `cdn-cgi` folder is created by CloudFlare and it's how the Rocket Loader works (https://www.statuscode.ch/blog/45002).

Answer (score 1):

Make a PHP file on your server that exports the IP in JSON format:

```
<?= json_encode (array ('ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS'])); ?>
```

Then call this file from your JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON("/json-ip-file.php",...
```

Comment: How to make this file attached with cloudflare?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "attached with CloudFlare". If you have mod_cloudflare then there is nothing you need to do special. Just upload the PHP file to your webserver and call it from JavaScript with $.getJSON.